# Como retornar a soma de valores de uma coluna com limit em MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

Quando executo diretamente no banco

`select sum(peso) from (select peso from dados order by id asc limit 2) as subt`

me retorna o valor esperado.

Quando executo no PHP com a variável  `$num=2` não há retorno de valor nem erro.

```
$consultar = ("select sum(peso) from (select peso from dados order by id asc limit $num) as subt");

$resulta = mysqli_query($link, $consultar);

while($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulta)){
       echo $item['subt'];
}
```

> O que pretendo é a soma dos valores das duas primeiras linhas da coluna `peso` da tabela

Que estou errando?

A tabela

[image: tabela]

Consulta direta no banco

[image: sum]

Comment: O problema parece estar em outro lugar, fora a falha de segurança: http://ideone.com/7nkJnl

Comment: O que pretendo é a soma dos valores das duas primeiras colunas da tabela

Comment: @MarceloBoni nada, nem soma nem erro

Comment: Não está aceitando com o limit.

Comment: @MarceloBoni >> connect success

Comment: Você defini subt como alias da sua subquery eu acho que o erro é esse " select sum(peso) total " deveria acessar assim : "echo $item['total']";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `AS` tem que ir no **sum(peso)** e não na "origem" do `from`, veja que pela sua própria imagem o nome da coluna veio como **sum(peso)** ao invés de `subt`:

[image: resultado]

O `AS` usado após o `FROM` seria para apelidar as tabelas e não as colunas, então se deseja nomear a coluna

> Nota o sub-select também precisa de `as` para evitar o erro:
>
> Every derived table must have its own alias.

O script parecia ter alguns problemas, já que disse que ocasionava o erro:

> PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ... 72 >> while($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulta)){

Refaça assim passando sempre o `$link`:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("seu dominio", "seu usuario", "sua senha", "nome do seu banco");

/* Verifica a conexão */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Conexão falhou: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

$num = 2;

$consultar = "SELECT SUM(peso) AS subt FROM (SELECT peso FROM dados ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $num) AS tabelaSubt";

if ($resulta = mysqli_query($link, $consultar)) {

    /* Pega os resultados */
    if ($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulta)) {
        echo $item["subt"];
    }

    /* limpa os resultados */
    mysqli_free_result($resulta);
} else {
    /* Mostra o erro caso a query falhar */
    echo mysqli_error($link);
}

/* fecha a conexão */
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Respondi isso acima tb no comentário divide a pontuação huahauhauha

Comment: Você é o cara !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!